# closed form expression for a sum? (combinatorics)

Tags: special-functions, enumerative-combinatorics

For non-negative integers $m$ and $n$, and positive real numbers $a$, $b$, define
$$\theta(m,n,a,b) := \underbrace{\sum_{p=0}^m \sum_{q=0}^n}_{p+q \; {\rm even}} \binom{m}{p} \binom{n}{q} \binom{p+q}{(p+q)/2} \:a^p \: b^q.$$

Is there a closed-form expression for this sum? Is it expressible in terms of some well-known special numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: The "enumerative-combinatorics" tag suggests that this arose in some enumeration problem $-$ what are you trying to use this sum for?

Comment: I don't expect a "closed form" but special values include $\theta(m,n,1,1)$ is the central trinomial coefficient of $(1+x+x^2)^{m+n}$. See on OEIS: http://oeis.org/A002426

Comment: It is very helpful actually. Thanks.

Comment: This sum shows up in a geometric analysis problem actually, related to Willmore surfaces.